# MongoDB : adding element to inner json object while both key-value stored in variables

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, nosql

i am trying to update a document in mongo db with nodejs native driver.

initially it was inserted like:

```
matches {
    _id:2001,
    requester:"MITH",
    accepter:"NIKK",
    toss:"MITH",
    bat:"NIKK",
    scores:{"MITH":220},
    status:0,
    won:"MITH"
}
```

now i need to update the document where i need to insert a new element `"NIKK":198` to scores object to make it `scores:{"MITH":220,"NIKK":198}`

problem is the key comes in a variable only. and when i update it is not updating

Below is the code with which i am trying

```
var _jsonMatch = {status:4};
var _scorepush = {}
_scorepush[variablevalue] = 198; // variablevalue in reference above is NIKK
var data = {"$set": _jsonMatch,"$push": {"scores":_scorepush} }
mith.findAndModify({_id:mith.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(matchId)},
        [],
        data,
        { upsert: true,new:true },
        function(error, match){ 
          if( error ) callback(error);
          else callback(null, match);
        });
```

**EDIT** :

I tried `$addToSet` instead of `$push` and i got the below error in callback with data undefined.

> { [MongoError: Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array]   name:
>   'MongoError',   lastErrorObject:    { err: 'Cannot apply $addToSet
>   modifier to non-array',
>        code: 12591,
>        n: 0,
>        connectionId: 56,
>        ok: 1 },   errmsg: 'Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array',   ok: 0 } undefined

Answer (score 4):

You need to build up your `$set` object programmatically to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#update-specification-documents) in the key that sets `'scores.NIKK'`.  So to update the doc you've shown above:

```
variablevalue = 'NIKK';
var set = {
    status: 4
};
set['scores.' + variablevalue] = 198;
mith.findAndModify({_id: 2001},
    [],
    { $set: set },
    { upsert: true, new: true },
    function(error, match){
        if( error ) callback(error);
        else callback(null, match);
    }
);
```

Note: the awkwardness of this is because you're using dynamic keys that you need to build up at run-time.  Consider re-working your schema so that `scores` is an array that looks something like this instead:

```
scores: [{name: 'MITH', value: 220}, {name: 'NIKK', value: 198}]
```

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me from wasting 3 hours trying to undo the nesting structure of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `$set` instead of `$push`:

```
var _jsonMatch = {status:4};
var _scorepush = {}
_scorepush[variablevalue] = 198; // variablevalue in reference above is NIKK
_jsonMatch["scores"] = _scorepush;
var data = {"$set": _jsonMatch };
mith.findAndModify({_id:mith.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(matchId)},
        [],
        data,
        { upsert: true,new:true },
        function(error, article){ 
          if( error ) callback(error);
          else callback(null, article);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks.. i will try with this and let you know.. :)

Comment: still its not updated .. i tried to access got as `{ "_id" : ObjectId("50f8ec6d527a262809000001"), "accepter" : "mithunsatheesh", "bat" : "mithunsatheesh", "requester" : "cricketfans", "scores" : { "mithunsathee
sh" : 30 }, "status" : 3, "toss" : "mithunsatheesh", "won" : "-" }`

Comment: Oops, I think it might just be `$set` not `$addToSet`

Comment: I tried this in beginning.. this overriden the initial value. resulting in only last insert in the json object `scores`.

Comment: Yea I don't think you can to it with an upsert, I believe you have to fetch the record, modify it, then save it.

Comment: there are two `set` in your answer corrently. you may merge the `_scorepush` into the  `_jsonMatch ` and try with one `set`.